# How do I download Chromiun

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, chromium, packages

I keep getting this popup from sudo and the store.

```
steve@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 chromium-browser : Depends: libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It says you have broken packages. Try to repair them with `sudo apt-get -f install`

If that doesn't fix your problem, you could find out which packages are currently on hold (maybe it's the package your desired software depends on, i.e. `libnss3-1d`):
`dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`
And then unhold (cancel) them and retry to install your desired package:
`sudo apt-mark unhold package_name`

Comment: how do I cancel them? @wullxz

Comment: unhold is a synonym for cancel in this case. Use `sudo apt-mark unhold package_name` like i wrote.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to trying to repair packages (i.e. `sudo apt-get -f install`) you should make sure your package cache is up to date.

```
sudo apt-get update
```